# Using NSFileHandle Properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

So I ran into a very weird issue this morning. I have an `NSMutableString` that constantly grows as time goes on, and it occasionally saves itself to the disk, basically creating a constantly growing text file. It was working perfectly, until a few hours ago. I changed none of the code in the method either by the way. This is the code I'm using, the `NSMutableString` is called stringToSave:

```
- (void)saveToTextFile {
    NSLog(@"SaveTextToFile called");

    // Get Current date and time:
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];

    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
    NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];

    NSString *dateToBeDisplayed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@, Time: %@.", theDate, theTime];


    // Create text to save, and save it.
    stringToSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n %@ ",dateToBeDisplayed];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mynotes"];

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
    [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [fileHandle writeData:[stringToSave dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [fileHandle closeFile];


    // Check what's saved there.
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];

    NSLog(@"File Content: %@", content);
    NSLog(@"stringtosave: %@", stringToSave);
}
```

The odd part is, `stringToSave` always has the proper data in it in the NSLog, while `content` remains empty. Does anyone see anything wrong with how I'm saving my data above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the file exist when you start?  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilehandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html says that if the file does not exist, then your fileHandleForWritingAtPath: returns nil.

The file would not exist if you delete and reinstall your app (either on the device on the the simulator).

Comment: Oh that might be the problem, because this only started happening when I reinstalled the app. Interesting. Do you know how I can create it if it's non existent?

Comment: Use fileExistsAtPath: and createFileAtPath: (see the docs at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: fileExistsAtPath is broken for me - and Apple's docs suggest they don't care (the header files specifically say not to use this method, that it doesn't reliably work)